# Hide some functions from .Rprofile

Tags: r, rprofile

I have several functions in my `.Rprofile` file:

```r
f1 <- function() { ...... }
f2 <- function() { ...... }
g <- function() { ...... }
```

The functions `f1` and `f2` are helper functions for `g`, and I don't want them in the global environnement. How could I do?

A solution is:

```r
g <- function() { 
  f1 <- function() { ...... }
  f2 <- function() { ...... }
  ......
}
```

but I don't like it.

Comment: The solution in the question keeps everything together and is easy to read.  I would keep it that way.

Answer (score 2):

I would include everything in a call to `local()` (and explicitly assign `g` to the global environment). This way, .Rprofile is self-contained and does not depend on external code.

```
# .Rprofile
local({
  f1 <- function() "foo"
  f2 <- function() "bar"
  assign("g", function() c(f1(), f2()), envir = globalenv())
})
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what we have packages for. Build a package containing your functions and load it in `.Rprofile`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I put `f1` and `f2` in a file in another folder (in the `inst` folder since I'm in a package) and I do that in `.Rprofile`:

```r
g <- function() {
  source("other/folder/file.R", local = TRUE)
  ......
}
```

Then when I run `g`, the functions `f1` and `f2` do not appear in the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are some obvious drawbacks, but maybe you can add a `.` at the beginning of the functions' name to hide them from the global environment:

```
.f1 <- function(...) {...}
.f2 <- function(...) {...}
g <- function(...) {...}
```